# Maven: Use assembly as resulting artefact - appendAssemblyId == false?

Tags: maven, replace, maven-assembly-plugin, artifact

I have a multimodule project.

Last module is "assemble", which is intended to put few modules' .jar's together in a single big .jar, which I could use for distribution.
This module does nothing else, so I did this:

```
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
           ...
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

I want this behavior to be able to simply run the resulting jar from IDE (NetBeans 7.0).

Maven does exactly what I want, but says this:

```
[assembly:single]
Reading assembly descriptor: src/assembly/assembly.xml
Building jar: /mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JBoss/bots/JawaBot/2.0/assemble/target/JawaBot-assemble-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing.
Instead of attaching the assembly file: /mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JBoss/bots/JawaBot/2.0/assemble/target/JawaBot-assemble-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, it will become the file for main project artifact.
NOTE: If multiple descriptors or descriptor-formats are provided for this project, the value of this file will be non-deterministic!
Replacing pre-existing project main-artifact file: /mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JBoss/bots/JawaBot/2.0/assemble/target/JawaBot-assemble-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
with assembly file: /mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JBoss/bots/JawaBot/2.0/assemble/target/JawaBot-assemble-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This message seems like it's not a recommended way to achieve my goal.
Is there any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly plugin will create an artifact with a 'classifier' consisting of the assembly ID from the descriptor. It won't create a main artifact AFAICT.

You might be happier with the maven-shade-plugin, plus configuring the maven-jar-plugin to set the manifest class name so that java -jar works. The shade plugin can produce a main artifact.